# react-native run-ios is having issues connecting to the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm having issues running my react-native app on the iOS Simulator.  It runs fine on my Windows machine on the Android simulator, so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my own code.

The issue seems to have something to do with permissions.

If I run `react-native run-ios` and the simulator as my user (not root), it seems to find the simulator fine, but I get an error during build:

```
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.656 xcodebuild[2612:76143] couldn't read dependency graph from '/Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/dgph': Permission denied
    
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.677 xcodebuild[2612:76144] couldn't read dependency graph from '/Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/dgph': Permission denied
    
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.677 xcodebuild[2612:76143] unable to create temporary file at /Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/dgph-1BUDub2D: Permission denied
    
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.677 xcodebuild[2612:76144] unable to create temporary file at /Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jschelpers.build/dgph-pZNRO08O: Permission denied
    
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.679 xcodebuild[2612:76144]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-11758/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
 Details:  unable to write dependency graph: Permission denied
 Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
 Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
 Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7facda2f3090>{number = 9, name = (null)}
 Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
 2017-03-12 14:22:05.679 xcodebuild[2612:76143]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-11758/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
 Details:  unable to write dependency graph: Permission denied
 Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
 Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
 Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7facd9f73a90>{number = 8, name = (null)}
   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    
 Build Preparation
    
 Couldn't create workspace arena folder '/Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build': Unable to write to info file '<DVTFilePath:0x7facd9e06ec0:'/Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/info.plist'>'.
    
 Couldn't update module cache session file '/Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation': You don’t have permission to save the file “Session.modulevalidation” in the folder “ModuleCache”.
    
    
    
 ** BUILD FAILED **
```

The simulator then does load the app, but has an error saying that it couldn't load from the module cache.

If I run `react-native run-ios` as root and the Simluator as my user, it says that it can't find a running simulated device.

If I run both as root, I get the following when running `react-native run-ios`:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AnxietyWorkTracker.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x44e
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.AnxietyWorkTracker
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x44e
```

The simulator does not load anything.

### Update

Per Rob's comment, I changed the permissions/owner on the directory.

```bash
sudo chown -R <username> <srcPath>
```

This allowed the build to succeed running as my non-root user.  Running `react-native run-ios` however built, opened the Simulator, opened the app in the Simulator, and then produced this error:

[image: react-native run-ios error]

Comment: All of my React Native project files are owned by `my user` and `staff`, whereas you're getting permission denied errors. Try changing the file ownership for your project (`chown -R jordan:staff Users/jordan/src/anxiety-work-tracker`) and re-running `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: Adding the permissions worked insofar as it let me run `react-native run-ios`.  Now, however, the Simulator is displaying the error `Native module cannot be null.` after loading the app.  Iirc, this is the same error it was getting when I ran both as my user *before* changing the owner--the major difference being that before `chown`, building itself was failing.  I'm uncertain as to whether this issue should be a new SO question or not.

Comment: Can you post the new error? Are you including React and React Native when creating new components?

Comment: @Rob I updated the OP.

Comment: And yes, I am including both React and React Native in each of my component files.

Comment: If the null module error persists after restarting the packager with `react-native start -- --reset-cache`, it is possibly caused by some dependency of your project. Had a similar problem with the latest v. of @remobile/react-native-file-transfer.

Comment: @NiFi yes, it looks like it's an issue with `react-native-push-notification`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I added this in an update to the OP, but I wanted this SO Question to be marked answered, since it has been.

Per Rob's comment, the issue was permissions on my source directory.

```bash
sudo chown -R <username> ~/src/<project-dir-name>
```